# change() for select element is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, node.js

I am learning Nodejs with node cookbook 2nd edition.

I like this book because it is teaching us with explaining sample code which looks very practical.

The example code is part of **Browser-server transmission via AJAX part**

Anyway the main question is that below is in the EX code, below is index.html file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            $.get("http://localhost:8080/profiles",function (profile_names) {
                $.each(profile_names, function (i, pname) {
                    $("#profiles").append("<option>" + pname + "</option>");
                });
            }, "json");
            $("#formats, #profiles").change(function () {
                alert("2");
                var format = $("#formats").val();
                $.get("http://localhost:8080/profile/" + $("#profiles").val() + "." + format,
                    function (profile, stat, jqXHR) {
                        var cT = jqXHR.getResponseHeader("Content-Type");
                        $("#raw").val(profile);
                        $("#output").html('');
                        if (cT === "application/json") {
                            $.each($.parseJSON(profile), function (k, v) {
                                $("#output").append("<b>" + k + "</b> : " + v + "<br>");
                            });
                            return;
                        }
                        if (cT === "application/xml") {
                            profile = jqXHR.responseXML.firstChild.childNodes;
                            $.each(profile, function (k, v) {
                                if (v && v.nodeType === 1) {
                                    $("#output").append("<b>" + v.tagName + "</b> : " + v.textContent + "<br>");
                                }
                            });
                        }
                    }, 
                "text");
            });
        </script>
        <style>
            #frm, #raw {display:block; float:left; width:210px},
            #raw {height:150px; width:310px; margin-left:0.5em}
        </style>
        <title> INDEX </title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <form id="frm">
            Profile: <select id="profiles">
            <option> </option>
            </select>
            <br></br>

            Format:<select id="formats">
            <option value="json"> JSON </option>
            <option value="xml"> XML </option>
            </select>
            <br></br>
            <div id="output"></div>
        </form>
        <textarea id="raw"></textarea>
    </body>
</html>
```

Second, server.js file

```
var http = require('http');
var fs = require('fs');
var path = require('path');
var profiles = require('./profiles');
var xml2js = require('xml2js');

var index = fs.readFileSync('index.html');
var routes, mimes = {xml: "application/xml", json: "application/json"}

function output(content, format, rootNode) {
    if (!format || format === 'json') {
        return JSON.stringify(content);
    }
    if (format === 'xml') {
        return (new xml2js.Builder({rootName: rootNode})).buildObject(content);
    }
}

routes = {
    'profiles': function (format) {
        return output(Object.keys(profiles), format);
    },
    '/profile': function (format, basename) {
        return output(profiles[basename], format, basename);
    }
};

http.createServer(function (request, response) {
var dirname = path.dirname(request.url),
    extname = path.extname(request.url),
// $.get('http://localhost:8080/profile/' + $('#profiles').val() + '.' + format
    basename = path.basename(request.url, extname);

    extname = extname.replace('.', ''); //remove period


    response.setHeader("Content-Type", mimes[extname] ||'text/html');

    if (routes.hasOwnProperty(dirname)) {
        response.end(routes[dirname](extname, basename));
        return;
    }
    if (routes.hasOwnProperty(basename)) {
        response.end(routes[basename](extname));
        return;
    }
    response.end(index);    
}).listen(8080);
```

below is profiles.js file

```
module.exports = {
    ryan: {
        name: "Ryan Dahl",
        irc: "ryah",
        twitter: "ryah",
        github: "ry",
        location: "San Francisco, USA",
        description: "Creator of node.js"
    },
    isaac: {
        name: "Isaac Schlueter",
        irc: "isaacs",
        twitter: "izs",
        github: "isaacs",
        location: "San Francisco, USA",
        description: "Former project gatekeeper, CTO npm, Inc."
    }
};
```

I think at index file  **$("#formats, #profiles").change(function () {** is not working.

I just input alert("2"); to test the code but I have never seen the alert.

I also tried to change code like

$("#formats").change(function () {,

$("#profiles").change(function () {

Both of them were not working neither.

Can you let me know what is the reason?

Comment: Good idea verifying your theory with alert, but you should learn to use the debugger in developer tools, it is much easier than debugging with alerts. In this case you could have stopped with a breakpoint and find out `$("#formats, #profiles")` is empty at that time.

Comment: @Iftah Thank you very much. I have a question. You said that I need to use debugger, I am using just editor 'sublime text2'. At this example code which is using Nodejs and jquery and ajax, which debugger can I use?

Comment: When you open the page in Chrome (recommended) or Firefox you can open Developer Tools (F12 in Chrome), with it you can view the client side code (not Node.js, but the javascript that is served to the browser) and you can set breakpoints, examine values, etc... I recommend the lessons 1-4 in the excellent free course https://www.codeschool.com/courses/discover-devtools

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either wrap your client-code in a DOM ready statement or move it to the end of the `<body>`. Your script is being executed before the page has rendered.

Comment: After I move the script code end of <body>, it is working. Thank you very much.